# Cant get attributes from error object

Tags: javascript

I am connecting to the Facebook API and I receive this error

```
{ [Error: failed [500] {"error":{"message":"Invalid parameter","type":"FacebookApiException","code":100,"error_subcode":1349125,"is_transient":false,"error_user_title":"Missing Message Or Attachment","error_user_msg":"Missing message or attachment."}}] stack: [Getter] }
```

I want to receive the `error_user_msg`

```
    try {
      var response = Social.createPosting(graphType, data);
    } catch (exception) {
      console.log(exception)
      throw new Meteor.Error(exception.error_user_msg)
    }
```

Problem is only `message` attribute is defined on the `Error` object that is returned.

`exception.message` returns

```
failed [500] {"error":{"message":"Invalid parameter","type":"FacebookApiException","code":100,"error_subcode":1349125,"is_transient":false,"error_user_title":"Missing Message Or Attachment","error_user_msg":"Missing message or attachment."}}
```

Which is a `String`, but is not valid JSON, so I cannot parse it either

What am I missing?

Comment: If you already know it's a string, why are you trying to tread it as if it's JSON? You could split the string and extract the JSON part, but if it's not defined to be a JSON string, will your solution be stable over time (What if the contents of the string changes?)

Comment: will it's returned by the facebook graph API, usually such return json so that is why i was confused

Comment: That doesn't exactly look like a string. Can you please `console.log(typeof exception, Object.getOwnPropertyNames(exception))`?